# Panel does not change Size.Width

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Good day all

**Problem:**

When creating the panel component, and assigning controls to it, with the

> autosize = true

the width property does not change at all, the size remains the same (X:200,Y:100 like a drag 'n drop panel size)

this panel is

> panel p

the panel's width changes when displayed (visually the width is different) but placing messagebox's displaying the width on designtime shows the panel with is 200.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void AddMessage(position pos, string owner, string _message)
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add's a label message panel to a parent panel
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pos">Use enum position, left is for message sent by you, right is message recieved.</param>
        /// <param name="_message">Message to display</param>
        owner += " :";

        Panel p = new Panel()
        {
            MaximumSize = new Size(((int)Math.Round(this.Width * 0.8, 0)), int.MaxValue),
            BackColor = (pos == position.left) ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightSkyBlue,
            AutoSize = false
        };
        Font bold = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, float.Parse((this.Font.Size*1.1).ToString()), FontStyle.Bold);
        Label O = new Label()
        {
            Location = new Point(_LABEL_MARGIN, _LABEL_MARGIN),
            AutoSize = true,
            Margin = new Padding(_LABEL_MARGIN),
            MaximumSize = new Size((int)Math.Round(p.MaximumSize.Width * 0.38, 0), int.MaxValue),
            Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(owner, bold, new Size((int)Math.Round((p.MaximumSize.Width) * 0.38, 0), int.MaxValue), TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis),
            Font = bold,
            Text = owner
        };
        MultiLineLabel l = new MultiLineLabel()
        {
            Location = new Point(O.Width + 5, _LABEL_MARGIN),
            AutoSize = false,
            Margin = new Padding(_LABEL_MARGIN),
            MaximumSize = new Size(p.MaximumSize.Width - p.Margin.All, p.MaximumSize.Height - p.Margin.All),
            Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(_message, this.Font, new Size(p.MaximumSize.Width - _LABEL_MARGIN - O.Width - O.Left, int.MaxValue), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak),
            Top = Top +3,
            Text = _message

        };
        p.Controls.Add(O);
        p.Controls.Add(l);
        p.Location = new Point((pos == position.left) ? 10 :(this.Width - (p.Width + 10)), lastTop);
        lastTop = _OBJEcT_BUFFER + p.Top + p.Height;
        this.Controls.Add(p);
    }
```

Comment: `AutoScroll`: Gets or sets a value indicating whether the container enables the user to scroll to any controls placed outside of its visible boundaries.

Comment: @MikkoViitala apologies, I meant autosize, see updated post

Comment: From the question("... but placing messagebox's displaying the width on designtime shows the panel with is 200") the issue is during design time?

Comment: You never set the width of the Panel control, so you end up with the control's default width setting...200.